# How to use gtkD in Win7 and dmd (D2)?

Tags: windows-7, d, dmd, gtkd

I downloaded `gtkD-1.5.1` and extracted to some `gtkD` directory. What do I do next ? I don't understand if I have to compile and link it to some lib or just link to it in my code ?

---

Edit: (@dsimcha)

the command `dsss build` in gtkD main dir gave me this:

```
Could not detect versions.
Could not detect versions.
Could not detect versions.
Could not detect versions.
Could not detect versions.
undemofy

Could not detect versions.
Could not detect versions.
atk => DO-atk

cairo => DO-cairo

gdk => DO-gdk

gdkpixbuf => DO-gdkpixbuf

gio => DO-gio

glade => DO-glade

glib => DO-glib

gobject => DO-gobject

gthread => DO-gthread

gtk => DO-gtk

gtkc => DO-gtkc

pango => DO-pango
```

but no lib was created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imanage to use GtkD without generating lib files, with rdmd.

1. You must install Gtk+2 runtime
2. Download GtkD source code to some dir
3. Run rdmd --build-only -I/src

rdmd will autobuild GtkD and your project code alone, skipping the need to making libs and linking it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems using DSSS on Windows as well, you could try using [Bud/Build](http://dsource.org/projects/build).

Make sure that build.exe is in your path somewhere, then open a command line in your gtkD/src/build folder. Then run `build gtkD.brf` to create `GtkD.lib`.

Depending on your version of DMD, you'll get a lot of errors. Most of the ones I got was typedef being deprecated. Any file where that happened (it will tell you) I simply refactored typedef into alias, and it worked fine. The other error I got was with `src/gtk/Toolbar.d`, and an ambiguous virtual function `getOrientation()`. To fix this, go into  `src/gtk/OrientableIF.d` and `/src/gtk/ToolShellIF.d` and comment out the getOrientation methods.

Using the most recent version of dmd (2.059), `glib/DateTime.d` won't compile. To make this file compile, simply comment out the method `override hash_t toHash()`.

When you compile your project, use `dmd <source files> -L <C:\Path\To\File>\GtkD.lib`

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile gtkD into a binary.  The standard way to do this is with [DSSS](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dsss).  Basically, download and install DSSS, and then do a `dsss build` from the main gtkD directory.

Edit:

After you build gtkD using DSSS, you'll have a bunch of .lib files in the gtkD directory.  You statically link these into your application.  In addition, you need to have the GTK+ libraries installed in your Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

**Building the Library**:
I would recommend taking a look at the [build guidelines for the project](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd/wiki/BuildingWithDSSS) here are the steps that they layout to build the library:

> 1. Get the latest stable version of DSSS and install it on your system.
> 2. [OPTIONAL]. Update the dsss.conf file in the root of the project to
>      suit your needs. Otherwise pay attention to the 'defaulttargets'
>      key. If you want a standard gtkD build/installation, the defaults
>      are fine.
> 3. Build gtkD. Go to the root of the project (where this file is
>      located) and run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    $ dsss build
>    ```
> 4. You may now install the libraries to your live filesystem. From the
>      root of the project, run:
>
>    ```
>    $ dsss install **--prefix=/usr/local**
>    ```
>
>    Don't forget to set the prefix according to your needs. "/usr/local"
>      is a sane default and should work on most systems without further
>      action. If the chosen prefix is not on your PATH, don't forget to
>      update your environment variables. Import files will also get
>      automatically installed to the chosen prefix. Note: root access may
>      be required to complete this step according to your system settings.
> 5. Build your own programs using the provided dsss.conf files from any
>      of the demo folders. Pay special attention to the buildflags used to
>      build the demos. "-L-ldl" is necessary on Linux systems.
> 6. Have fun!

**Using the Library:**
After that you can then use the library in a few different ways in your own program [depending on how your building it](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dsss/wiki/DSSSByExample):

If you are using DSSS to build your own project then all you need to do is import the modules in code like this:

```
import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.Main;

void main(string[] args)
{
    Main.init(args);
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow("Hello World");
    win.setDefaultSize(200, 100);
    win.add(new Label("Hello World"));
    win.showAll();

    Main.run();
}
```

Your dss.conf would look like this:

```
name = helloworld
[helloworld.d]
target = helloworld
```

And use the normal steps to build and install it:

```
$ dsss build
$ dsss install
```

**Edit:**:
I just noticed that you want to use DMD directly, to compile your project you can use:

```
dmd helloworld.d -ofhelloworld -L+gtk.lib
```

Please note that this build style is not recommended for larger projects and you should use DSSS whenever practical.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the latest release doesn't always work out of the box, you are better off with trunk HEAD by going to http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd/browser/trunk and clicking the Zip Archive link at the bottom, the version that worked for me was [r952](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd/changeset/952/trunk?old_path=/&format=zip).

Download [bud/build](http://dsource.org/projects/build)(version 3.04 worked fine) and call it like this
    build gtkD.brf

The error

> Could not detect versions

is caused by not having dmd in path.

I tried gtkD 1.5.1 which is the current latest but then I got the typedef problem and after I fixed it manually I got the XOverlay problem and after a lot of searching I found that they are both fixed in SVN so I got trunk HEAD and it worked out of the box.